# ASP.NET Core 6 - Model binding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to edit blogs but my ViewModel can't get `CategoryId` and `BlogId`.

[image]

This is the edit view:

[image]

I can get other data for example `Title`, `Description` but `CategoryId` returns 0.

This is BlogEditVM:

[image]

If you need more details I can edit my post, thanks.

Comment: Post your code as code, not as images. You will get better help (and less downvotes) that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `CategoryId` value as `Category.CategoryId` to API action. Hence, you cannot get the `CategoryId` value from the `BlogEditVM` object in the API action.

You need to specify the `name` attribute in the `<select>` element as below:

```
<select asp-items="@ViewBag.values"
    asp-for="@Model.Category.CategoryId"
    class="form-control"
    name="CategoryId">
    ...
</select>
```